Run in vscode does nothing
When I try to run any python script in my venv in vscode nothing happens except the debug tool bar pops up briefly and goes away. Didnt have any issues now its not working without me knowingly changing anything. I can run properly if I manually type the program into the python terminal. Is there a way to tell what vscode is trying to run?
Tried restarting
closing all the folders
ctrl+shift+n
interpreter path is set to python in the venv
this is my launch.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            
        },
          
    ]
}


what versions of VS code and debugpy, are you using?

Also, what version of Python are you running in the venv?

Would you mind sharing more details about this question?Python version vsc version,and which OS are you running on?

Did you set a breakpoint to check your debugger? Maybe your python script is too short, and the debug process has already completed.

This is a bug in VSCode.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/228191
It has been fixed yesterday (2024-09-24), but probably not rolled to the release you are using yet.
You can switch to VSCode Insiders release, which has the fix.
Or you can try removing the
"console": "integratedTerminal"

option, which I think is related to the issue.
